# How to send file from server using telebot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I made a bot that sends files from an external server with a URL.

I want the bot to send files directly from your server.

What am I doing wrong? Why didn't the `open()` command work?

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("Token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start','help'])
def send_start_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hi.")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def echo_all(message):
    print(message.text)
    duck = open('duck.png','r')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, duck)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "hi")

bot.polling()
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to tell [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) to use **binary mode**;

```py
duck = open('duck.png', 'rb')
```

[Read more about `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

---

Minimal working example to send **local** image:

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("<YOUR-TOKEN-HERE>")
cid = <YOUR-ID-HERE>

img = open('image.jpg', 'rb')
bot.send_photo(cid, img)
```