# How to send documents like html in telebot python or with api

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

```
import requests

files = {
    'chat_id': (None, '1937802988'),
    'document': ('answer.html', open('answer.html', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/<token>/sendDocument', files=files)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send file from server using telebot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292828/how-to-send-file-from-server-using-telebot)

Answer (score 0):

To send documents via telebot use send_document.
This example sends HTML and PDF files.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('<TOKEN>')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):

    html_doc = open('answer.html', 'rb')
    bot.send_document(message.from_user.id, html_doc);

    pdf_doc = open('file.pdf', 'rb')
    bot.send_document(message.from_user.id, pdf_doc);

bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval=0)
```